# Is an equation that has partial differentiation with respect to only one of the independent variables, still classified as a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, definition

I have gotten into a bit of an argument with my supervisor about the semantics of what constitutes a PDE. Effectively it comes down to an equation that looks like
$$ \gamma(\dot{q})\ddot{q}(t, x) = - \omega^2 q + k x$$
where
$$\gamma(v) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2}}$$ which I call a partial differential equation. My supervisor tends to disagree citing that though $q(t, x)$ is a multivariate function, but differentiation is still with respect to $t$, that what we have is an Ordinary differential equation, with parametric dependence on $x$.

Is there a definitive authority (preferably a textbook) on PDEs that I can cite to convince my supervisor, among others that it is indeed a PDE, rather than a parametric ODE.

**some background**; (in case it's an X/Y problem):

This is one of two Euler-Lagrange equations of of a relativistic coupled harmonic oscillator. The particular derivation, basically assumes that you can parameterise $x = x(t)$ and solve the second equation without the $\gamma$ to get $q(t; x)$, but I argue that to do that you need to use proper time and that makes things much more complicated. So I say, let's treat this as if $x(t)$ were unknown, and varied as a free variable.

**EDIT**: The overdot means differentiation with respect to coordinate time $t$. The problem arose because I wrote it to mean $\partial_t$ whereas my supervisor insists that it is more akin to $\dfrac{d}{dt}$.

**EDIT2**: This may not be clear from the text, but the question isn't can this be regarded as an ODE (it clearly can be), but ore along the lines of, can this *also* be regarded as a PDE?

Comment: i don’t see why you would bother arguing about this, but at least one  ‘reason’ for calling it an ODE is that theorems about ODEs apply. Also, it is an ODE with a parameter, so you will not convince your supervisor that it is anything ‘rather than’ what it is. At best, you can only hope to convince that it is a PDE, ‘as well as’ an ODE with a parameter

Comment: Well, I'm not trying to prove that this isn't an ODE, I'm trying to convince him that this is *also* a PDE, if you treat $q(t, x)$ as a multivariate function.